# How does tawakkul relate to depression and anxiety?

Tags: imaan, qadar, sick, depression, tawakkul

I suffer from depression, anxiety and OCD. A scholar told me to believe in tawakkul of Allah. Can you explain what that is and how does it relate to my mental health please?

Answer (score -1):

Tawakkul: Trust In Allah

> Verse (65:3) And will provide for him from where he does not expect.
>   And whoever relies upon Allah - then He is sufficient for him. Indeed,
>   Allah will accomplish His purpose. Allah has already set for
>   everything a [decreed] extent.

Another verse for al-Imran

> Verse (3:160) If Allah should help you, no one can overcome you; but if He should
>   forsake you, who is there that can help you after Him? And upon Allah
>   let the believers rely.

Comment: Given that OP has asked a clear and focused question this is a poor answer and needs some real elaboration (see [answer]).

Comment: Bro Yas: try to understand these verses, if cannot then hard to explain anything, these are the words of God not mine.

Comment: Evidences are not self-explanatory therefore you should explain and elaborate else your answer is rather useless! See [on meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/do-evidences-speak-for-themselves).